# Dataframe query - compare string in column with a string

Tags: python, dataframe

inside a dataframe query i want to compare to strings that contains whitespaces. I think that the whitespaces a the problem.

| name | text |
| --- | --- |
| carol | drinks |
| mary | two drinks |

```
df_rc = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

for index, string_to_compare in df_rc.iterrows:
```

example 1: "drinks"

data = "drinks"
column_name is also "drinks"

```
df = df_data.query('column_name == @string_to_compare["data"])
```

example 2: "two drinks"

data = "two drinks"
column_name is also " two drinks"

```
df = df_data.query('column_name == @string_to_compare["data"])
```

That works fine for example 1, but example 2 has no matches.

example 1 returns 1 line
example 2 is always empty but expected 1

Whats wrong here?

Comment: what is string_to_compare?

Comment: answer added to question

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: please review Stackoverflow guidlines here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  to help provide with a reproducible example